# How to merge audio video file in mac system using action script?

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am creating a screen recording application using action script. I am able to record the screen and audio files separately but the issue i am facing is that i am not able to merge these audio and video files in Mac.

For windows version i have used the ffmpeg and it is working fine But for Mac system it is not working. Do you guys have any other suggestions or any way to run the ffmpeg from the action script directly for Mac ?

Comment: This? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html

Comment: I am using the NativeProcess to run the ffmpeg binary file which is available in its website [link](http://www.ffmpegmac.net) , but it is not working. Have you run the ffmpeg in mac using NativeProcess? If you have done it can you share the code.

Comment: Nope, I just checked because you didn't tell what you've tried so far.